# Value lost in JSON.stringify In $.ajax function

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, stringify

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {                 
        $("#btnPost").click(function () {
            var sof = {
                EndUserIp: "192.168.10.10",
                TokenId: $("#pageInitCounter").val(),
                AdultCount: $("#AdultCount").val(),
                ChildCount: $("#ChildCount").val(),
                InfantCount: $("#InfantCount").val(),
                DirectFlight: "false",
                OneStopFlight: "false",
                JourneyType: $("#JourneyType :selected").text(),
                PreferredAirlines: null,         
            }
          alert(JSON.stringify(sof));
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "/api/Flight/SearchFlight",
                    type: "Post",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(sof),
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });        
        });
    });
  </script>
```

This is the simple code in Script tage.There is a json Object array.I have named it sof.I am initialising value for each of the objects through Id selector on click Event from each of textboxes, dropdowns etc.

Now, as u can see there is a alert box after sof json array.

```
   alert(JSON.stringify(sof));
```

It is showing exact and correct values whatever is selected in dropdown.

**But problem appears here at $.Ajax function call.**
I want to return back Json array to url stated in function but when i hover over sof , it strangely have some values from textboxes correct but from dropdown like JourneyType, its returning null.

One more thing, since the alert box is returning all the correct values But when i hover over sof in alert box after alert box is being closed, i can see that textboxes value are correct but dropdown value(JourneyType) is null here .Now, how it could happen, since alert box have shown me the correct dropdown's value selected.

and this is my simple dropdown:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JourneyType, Model.JourneyList, new {id = "JourneyType"})
```

Please someone tell me what is happening here.
This is the full html rendered.I have copied code from view source.

```
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DepartmentID">Journey Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <select id="JourneyType" name="JourneyType"><option value="0">OneWay</option>
 <option value="1">Return</option>
 <option value="2">MultiStop</option>
 <option value="3">AdvanceSearch</option>
 <option value="4">SpecialReturn</option>
 </select>
 <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="JourneyType" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
           </div>
       </div>
```

This is the model class:

```
    public enum JourneyType
{
    OneWay, Return, MultiStop, AdvanceSearch, SpecialReturn
}
public enum FlightCabinClass
{
    All, Economy, PrimiumEconomy, Business, PremiumBusiness, First
}
public class SearchForFlight
{
    public SearchForFlight()
    {
        JourneyList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        FlightCabinClassList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    public string EndUserIp { get; set; }
    public string TokenId { get; set; }
    public int AdultCount { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JourneyList { get; set; }

    public int ChildCount { get; set; }
    public int InfantCount { get; set; }
    public bool DirectFlight { get; set; }
    public bool OneStopFlight { get; set; }
    public Enum JourneyType { get; set; }
    public string PreferedLines { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public Enum FlightCabinClass { get; set; }
 //   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PreferredDepartureTime { get; set; }
//    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PreferredArrivalTime { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FlightCabinClassList { get; set; }
    public string Sources { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: _"but dropdown value(JourneyType) is null here"_ Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 i have included html at the last.Please see updated ques

Comment: Is an `option` selected when `#btnPost` element is clicked?

Comment: yes i can see correct selected text in alert box but then dont know where it get lost

Comment: @duke Where is it getting lost ? You can save that in a var `var data =JSON.stringify(sof);` and `console.log(sof);`  And what are you receiving at the server ?

Comment: I have tried console.log its returning correct value but in $.ajax, value get lost @Chintan

Comment: What is the method you are posting this back to? And its just `data: sof,` and you need to remove the `contentType` option. And `sof` is an object,  not an array!. And remove the pointless `new {id = "JourneyType"}` from your `DropDownListFor()` method

Comment: I am posting back data to url api/Flight/SearchFlight.It's an web api action method.Now as u said i have removed new { id = "JorneyType"} and removed ContentType too. Still null in JourneyType and in some other properties too @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then show the method and the model you posting back to. You statement _but in $.ajax, value get lost_ is nonsense. Nothing is 'lost'. If its not binding to your model, then its the code in your model and controller which is the issue

Comment: [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SearchFlight([FromBody]SearchForFlight sof)
        { } i have not written full code just checking right now all the values and included model in updated ques

Comment: `public JourneyType JourneyType { get; set; }` not `public Enum JourneyType { get; set; }`

Comment: thnk u very much sir @StephenMuecke once again saved my time

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thnks to Mr. StephenMuecke.
There was a Small mistake in my code due to which Returned value was wrong.
After changing return type for JourneyType property from enum to JourneyType, everthing worked fine.

```
    public JourneyType JourneyType { get; set; }
```

not

```
    public Enum JourneyType { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you change your question sentence? its not "Value lost in JSON.stringify In $.ajax function" since in $.ajax function, the value still remains the same, but the value is not binding in the action method(server side)